# Is there a tool that can scan an asp.net project and build a sitemap?

Tags: asp.net, html, sitemap

I'm looking for an automated way to inventory all the links within an asp.net project that I inherited.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing a project on codeproject where he built the sitemap dynamically, so everytime he added a page it would add it to the site map. Good for dynamically generated pages.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/dynamicsitemap.aspx